# WPF. Group items in ListBox without ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I add items to `ListBox` like this;

```
tvProgramListBox.Items.Add(r);
```

And after adding all objects I'm trying to group items like this;

```
CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(tvProgramListBox.Items);
PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("date");
view.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
```

or like this;

```
PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("date");
tvProgramListBox.Items.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
tvProgramListBox.Items.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
```

`date` property  exists in items. However, `ListBox` does not group items. When I used `ItemsSource` binding before, grouping was working. But there is many items in my collection and I decided to add them manually to `ListBox` in the background thread to keep UI free from freezes. So now it doesn't freeze, but doesn't group either :)
Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Delete all that and use proper databinding.

Comment: @HighCore i need to add items to listbox from background thread

Comment: No you don't. You need to deal with your `data` in a background thread, which has nothing to do with the UI. Delete all that and use proper databinding.

Comment: @HighCore if I add my items to an itemssource from a background thread, ui doesn't change

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add items to your collection in a background thread but still use `ItemsSource` you can use `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` to do so.

Add this using statement:

```
using System.Windows.Data;
```

You'll need an object for the binding engine to lock on in addition to your collection:

```
ObservableCollection<MyType> Source = new ObservableCollection<MyType>();
object myLock = new object();
```

Now you can enable the synchronization where appropriate.

```
BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(Source, myLock);
```

You should now be able to update the collection from a background thread while still using `ItemsSource` on the `ListBox`.

Comment: I see. In that case, you may wish to try this answer's suggestion to use a BackgroundWorker and its report progress handler: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32633164/1231132