# Update ObservableCollection from background Worker

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, datagrid

I have a DatGrid, which is bound to `var Result_Full = new ObservableCollection<IP_DataRow>()`. This is a simple class containing several **string & double** variables. Nothing difficult.

What I do, is that I read an Excel File (with Telerik RadSpreadProcessing), which parses rows into my class. I do this on a thread so that the UI is not blocked. I have encountered a few problems though:

1) I cannot use `ref` keyword in a long process which reads excel file (because Result_Full is a public property bound to a DataGrid), but I have to create temporary `ObservableCollection<IP_DataRow>()`, where the values are placed. Once the process has finished I run the following script for copying the values:

```
        foreach (var item in tmpFull)
        {
            InvokeOnUIThread(() =>
            {
                Result_Full.Add(item);
            });
        }
```

*What I would like to do, is to be able to see in a real time (if possible) how items are being added to the collection in my DataGrid.*

As I am using .Net 4.5 I tried to implement `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` as was suggested by some other post, yet I could not figure out how to bind my UI bould collection **Result_Full** to temporary used in a process.

2) Even with the current setup, when (under my UI) I move to my Tab which contains DataGrid (my DataGrid is on a different TabPage), and I try to add new item to the collection with the above mentioned code, it returns an error saying: **The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.**, which is rather weird, as **InvokeOnUIThread** is nothing else but `Dispatcher.Invoke()`, which should be thread safe?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

EDIT: Showing more code:

This is the process I call from BackgroundWorker:

```
    public void ProcessFile()
    {
        var tmpError = new ObservableCollection<IP_DataRow>();
        var tmpFull = new ObservableCollection<IP_DataRow>();

        var _reader = new IP_ExcelReader(sExcelPath, ref tmpError, ref tmpFull);
        string sResult = _reader.ReadExcelFile();
        if (sResult != string.Empty)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error processing selected Excel File!" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Error message:" + Environment.NewLine + sResult);
        }

        foreach (var item in tmpError)//populates error list
        {
            IP_InvokeOnUIThread(() =>
            {
                Result_Error.Add(item);
            });
        }

        foreach (var item in tmpFull)//populates full list
        {
            IP_InvokeOnUIThread(() =>
            {
                Result_Full.Add(item);
            });
        }

        OnPropertyChanged("Result_Full");
        //OnPropertyChanged("Result_Error");

        iSelectedTabIndex = 1;

    }
```

Here you can see, that I have to create temporary collection **tmpError, tmpFull** where I gather my data. At the end of process, I manually copy values into my main collections bound to DataGrid. I would like to change this, meaning that values are copied to the main collection (not temporary ones) during the process, so that user can see in a real time how values are added to the collection.

P.S.2:
for uknown reason to me, one of the problems lied in my `InvokeOnUIThread` call. Once I changed from `App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);` to `App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);` error with **..different thread owns it** stopped.

Comment: Which thread owns 'item' and 'tmpFull'?

Comment: *Which dispatcher?*  Dispatcher.Current is kept in TLS, so every thread will have its own dispatcher.  You need to access the UI thread's dispatcher.

Comment: I am using **App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);**. I though that is the UI dispatcher? How do I access it then?

Comment: foreach call is executed in the Background Worker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can use BackgroundWorker instead of thread, to report progress as it goes.
   [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners) is a simple tutorial
2. I believe that simply calling Dispatcher will use thread of a context, which is not UI-thread in your case. Try `Application.Current.Dispatcher` instead

In short, I believe you should do the following:

1. Create public ObservableCollection in UI-thread and bind it to DataGrid
2. Create a background worker. Set reporting to true. Subscribe to ReportProgress and DoWork events.
3. Run worker async
4. In DoWork handler create a list and read some amount of values to it. As you reach some amount, let's say a hundred, call `(sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress` method, passing in event args this collection you have populated.
5. In report progress handler, populate your ObservableCollection from a list you've passed throught event args.
6. Steps 4 - 5 are repeated until everything is done

Comment: I am already using background worker. The problem I have is, that I don't know how to connect my temporary collection with collection bound to the DataGrid? This means, that I am only populating my values, once my Excel reading void finishes. I will share more code

Comment: I ended up passing BackgroundWorker as a ref parameter to my Excel Reading function, and there I called the ProcessChanged method, which did the trick!